# BitmapSource into a stream Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a class which requires a Stream to rotate an image from the phone camera.  The problem I have is that when loading the picture from isolated storage (ie after the user has saved the picture previously) it is loaded into a BitmapSource.

I would like to 'extract' the bitmap source back into a stream if possible? does anyone know if it is using silverlight for WP7?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)img);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {

    bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: For me it does't work! The [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) don't have the method SaveJpeg.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pull it back into a BitMap source directly, but you can get there through the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` class.

Here's my version of your class whose method accepts a stream (your code obviously does more than mine, but this should be enough for our purposes).

```
public class MyPhotoClass
{
    public BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapSource(Stream stream)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(stream);
        return img;
    }
}
```

Then calling that class with data from the file we pulled from Isolated Storage:

```
private void LoadFromIsostore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = file.OpenFile("saved.image", FileMode.Open))
        {
            MyPhotoClass c = new MyPhotoClass();
            BitmapSource picture = c.ConvertToBitmapSource(fs);
            MyPicture.Source = picture;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we're using the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` object returned from the `OpenFile` method directly. It's a stream, which is what ConvertToBitmapSource expects.

Let me know if that's not what you're looking for or if I misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
        var background = Brushes.Transparent;

        var bmp = Viewport3DHelper.RenderBitmap(viewport, 500, 500, background);

        BitmapEncoder encoder;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        switch (ext.ToLower())
        {

            case ".png":
                var png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
                encoder = png;
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Not supported file format.");
        }

        //using (Stream stm = File.Create(FileName))
        //{
        //    encoder.Save(stm);
        //}

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);

            this.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
```