# Convert Image Data to Stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream, converters, exif

I'm trying to convert Image Data to Stream for get ExifInfo/Metadata

```
 MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
 Picture photoFromLibrary = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["FileId"]);
```

`photoFromLibrary.GetImage();` returns only `ImageData`

I need it to use in my method

```
public static void GetMetaData(Stream photo)
{
    ExifLib.JpegInfo info = ExifLib.ExifReader.ReadJpeg(photo);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(photo);
    App.MainViewModel.MetaDate = ReadExif(info);
}
```

`ExifLib.ExifReader.ReadJpeg(photo);` needs a stream

So what I get from `photoFromLibrary.GetImage();` is `ImageData`, but I need a `stream`. So how can I convert `ImageData` to `stream`?

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: how to convert image data to stream

Answer (score 0):

```
       I hope your are looking for this result.            


        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(ContentPanel, new TranslateTransform());

        using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"));
                wb.SaveJpeg(stream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `WriteableBitmap` to convert the `Image` into a `stream`?

[BitmapSource into a stream Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325293/)